# Eclipse plugin view - How to add and dispose composites on the fly

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, jfreechart

The Use Case is simple:

In a Scrolled Composite, I have a Dropdown menu and, when I select an item from it, several ChartComposites spawn in a grid layout underneath.

I then select the dropdown again, I click another item, all previously spawned composites are disposed and the view is populated with new ones.

Now for more details:

Both the Dropdown and the ChartComposites are contained in a regular Composite
(because I can only set one Composite to the ScrolledComposite) which has a grid layout, because I want them arranged in a certain way.

The problem is I have no idea how I can call the createPartControl() after the view has been created in order to dispose of the composites I no longer want and create the new composites.

I tried using a Content Provider but I don't think it works for premade Composites, because the results were that the ChartComposites it was supposed to return got cast into Objects and were no longer...charts.

I considered using a StackLayout but I really need the GridLayout I currently have so that doesn't work.

So does anyone know a quick and easy way to dispose of and add composites to an already created view through listeners (select a dropdown item, push a button etc)?

Comment: You can combine StackLayout and GridLayout to achieve this without messing around trying the dispose things.

Comment: Can I use them both in the same composite or do I have to make another composite that contains solely the charts(arranged by a grid layout) while the other composite contains the dropdown and this composite, using a StackLayout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `StackLayout` and `GridLayout` to achieve this without having to mess around with `dispose`.

It is not clear from your question exactly what the GUI design is. The following code stacks multiple composite children:

```
Composite parent = new Composite(body, SWT.NONE);
parent.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
StackLayout layout = new StackLayout();
parent.setLayout(layout);

Composite child1 = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
child1.setLayout(new GridLayout());
// TODO .... add controls to child1 for first 'page'

Composite child2 = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
child2.setLayout(new GridLayout());
// TODO .... add controls to child2 for second 'page'

layout.topControl = child;
layout.layout();
```

Comment: I'll have to take a look and see if I can make something of it. I noticed the StackLayout can put ONE composite on top, that being the composite i choose. For me it's a bit more complicated I want to be able to add up to 200 composites in the view and at the press of a button get rid of all of them and put 100 others in their place. Maybe it might work if I put them into a group or in a composite acting as their container and put that one as the StackLayout page.

Comment: You just put all your Composites as children of the single Composite.

Comment: I also noticed the setContent(composite) method of the ScrolledComposite can be called from a listener and it changes the scrolled area on the fly. Any downfall to using it?

Comment: It is intended that you call setContent exactly once. I have no idea what would happen if you called it multiple times.

Comment: After about 10 times and 2000 composites created (in total, yeah i have about 200 charts at once), it crashes with org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles. Funny, although I didn't exactly dispose each and every font and color, I do dispose the previous composite that contains  the charts before creating another one with which to switch.

Comment: Apparently the memory leak was a JFreeChart issue with it's ChartComposite. Workaround is extending the class and overriding its dispose() method to get rid of all MenuItems from the popupMenu (which don't get disposed normally along with the class). I'll mark your answer as accepted since it really helped me!